# Favorites List using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, combobox

I am trying to create a favorites list using a loop. I created a combobox with different options, and a ActiveX Command button to execute the code. Right now when you press the enter button, all 10 cells are filled with whatever is currently selected in the combobox. I only want one cell to be filled at a time per combobox selection.

```
  Dim x As Integer
  For x = 8 To 18
         Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 19).Value = ComboBox1.Value
  Next x
```

Comment: Well, you are looping through the 10 cells and set them to `ComboBox1.Value` so that would be expected. Do you want to add the current value to the first empty cell?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the value to the first empty cell only, you can just check if it is empty first with an `IF`. And then exit the loop once a value has been added, so that you don't fill up all the empty ones.
Would something like this work perhaps?

```
Dim x As Integer      
For x = 8 To 18             
    if Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 19).Value = "" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 19).Value = ComboBox1.Value
        Exit For        
    end if
Next x
```